# D3 Globe pointer issue on map move

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, d3.js, webgl-globe

I have created globe using D3. I am facing issue when I move map its Pointer also move along with map that is okay, but currently the Pointer is going out of map area when Map is moved.

Please check below link for demo
http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/

Comment: Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: http://projectsdemo.net/globe/v4/js/globe.js

Comment: I have fixed issue of pointer going out of map but now it should hide when map goes behind.

Comment: When people say "please post the relevant code", what they mean is (a) the code needs to be in the question itself, and (b) only the relevant snippet. You may _additionally_ supply a JS Fiddle if that helps demonstrate the issue.